# Synonym for "overclock" for general electrical appliances

Tags: word-request, synonyms

When a CPU is running with performance exceeding its spec, it is said to be "overclocked". I'm looking for a word with a similar meaning that could be applied to general electrical appliances or power tools. The word *overclocked* sounds clumsy when applied to a hair drier or a toaster.

The word *overpowered* sounds right from the physical point of view, but that means "too powerful" by design (thanks @AricFowler) or "defeated" by something more powerful, rather than "running over the spec".

Then there's the word *overdriven* and *overdrive*. Can it be applied to things like a toaster? Or does it only work with appliances which have an actual drive?

Comment: Overpowered is more commonly used to describe something that is too powerful, or so powerful it dominates other things in the same group: "This electric drill is overpowered". If something is "being overpowered" or "has been overpowered" then it is defeated, as you said.

Comment: Could you explain how you might make a toaster "more powerful"? Or another related "power-up" electrical device? I realize yours is a language question, but I would like to understand the reality of such a situation. Maybe some other word could be apparent.

Comment: @user3169 For example, one could increase the voltage to make the toaster produce more heat.

Comment: @DmitryGrigoryev You could, but that would be a dangerous, right (shock or fire hazard). It's different from a CPU that should have redundant protection.

Comment: @user3169 Toasters also have thermal protection, without it they're already a fire hazard even at their nominal power.

Comment: @DmitryGrigoryev Of course. I wasn't trying to discuss electrical/electronic theory, but rather looking for a practical example that you could apply any "overpowered" like answers to.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe you could use the phrase "**revved up**" for speed and power but some people do use "**overclocked**" for whatever they want. You could also use "**improved**" and "**enhanced**". the word "**boost**" can also work in some contexts.

Comment: "boost" sounds nice, thanks. But what about "overdrive"? Does it have a connotation of rotary motion (like "revved up") or not?

Comment: You should add how these phrases could be "applied to general electrical appliances or power tools", since that is what the question asks. Just listing synonyms doesn't really do that.